# To edit part of a line in a QlistWidget using python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

My list widget placed inside a window prints out values (0 - 1000) when button1 is pressed. But some of these values are 0's and signify an error. The user is expected to update these values with any other positive integer. Once the value is confirmed by pressing a button2, the list will be updated or an error is shown that it needs to be further updated.

The following is my code.

```
import Ui_ImageSort # designed using Qt-Designer
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QListWidgetItem

class ImageSort(Ui_ImageSort.Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImageSort, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(list_view)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(print_scales)

    def list_view(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()
        for i in range(len(self.scale_txt)):
            item = QListWidgetItem(str(self.scale_txt[i]))
            self.listWidget.addItem(str(i + 1) + ") " + item.text())            

    def print_scales(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()
        error = 0
        for i in range(len(self.scale_txt)):
            if (self.scale_txt[i]==0):
                error = 1

        if (error ==0):
            self.listWidget.addItem("\nThe scale values are confirmed ")
            for i in range(len(self.scale_txt)):
                    print(self.scale_txt[i])
                    print("\n")
        else:
            self.listWidget.addItem("\nThe scale values have an error")
            self.listWidget.addItem("Press button 1 again to edit")
```

I would like to edit only the digits the the listwidget prints out. The output will look something like this:

> 1) 100 microns 
>  
>   2) 200 microns 
>  
>   3) 0 microns 
>   4) 100 microns

The value 0 needs to be corrected. So it should be marked red. And the user can change without affecting the remaining line ("microns").  For example: "0 microns" is invalid, marked in red and should be editable, but after the user replaces it with some other digits, presses button2, then it becomes valid and is, therefore, turned black and is no longer editable.

Comment: you could explain yourself better

Comment: I have made a few changes

Comment: you point out that 0 is an invalid value, that is just an example, do not you have a more general criterion ?, for example -50 is valid, are valid values only positive? Is 50.5 valid?

Comment: PyQt4 or PyQt5??

Comment: I use PyQt5 (I will update the tags). I intend to add only positive integer values to the list. I make some comparison checks before appending the list by comparing the accuracy of the value with existing images. In questionable cases, I add 0 to the list. So that the user can make changes manually later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a delegate, and the data is passed through the roles:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

MaskRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000

class ListDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        mask = index.data(MaskRole)
        if mask is not None:
            editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent)
            editor.setInputMask(mask)
            return editor

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if editor.hasAcceptableInput():
            text = editor.text()
            model.setData(index, text, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

        re = QtCore.QRegularExpression(r"(\d+)\) (\d+) microns")
        match = re.match(index.data())
        color = QtGui.QColor("red")
        if match.hasMatch():
            val = match.captured(match.lastCapturedIndex())
            if val != "0":
                color = QtGui.QColor("black")
        model.setData(index, color, QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    delegate = ListDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    scales = [100, 200, 0, 500, 0, 300, 0]
    for i, scale in enumerate(scales):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        if scale == 0:
            item.setData(MaskRole, "{}) 900 micro\\ns".format(i))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            item.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.red)
        item.setText("{}) {} microns".format(i, scale))
        w.addItem(item)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry, will it be more correct to change the line `if editor.hasAcceptableInput ():` to `if editor.hasAcceptableInput() and model.data(index)!=editor.text():` ?

Comment: @S.Nick Why do you think that?

Comment: @S.Nick I assumed that if an acceptable value was already taken, the item should not be editable, so the second check will always be given.

Comment: Because if you go into editing and without doing anything above, you can’t re-enter editing.

Comment: @abk 1. The 900 has nothing to do with MVC, this has to do with the inputmask of QLineEdit, for more information read: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop. 2. Your second question I can not answer because I do not know how it has its code since it has not provided a [mcve]. Finally, have you tested my code? Does it work as you require?

Comment: @abk But you just pointed out that the items that can be editable are only the invalid items. Do you want all the items to be editable?

Comment: @abk please be more precise in your question, it seems to me that you assume that certain things are evident but not because I only base myself on what is explicitly stated in your question or in the answers to my questions that are in the comments.

Comment: No, I do not want to edit the other values. I think the editable part that I mentioned above already exist here. And the code works in a way that I can try to test and see further changes. The parent class is different from my original code. Nevertheless, a python example given here is a good start for me.

Comment: @abk I do not understand you, explain, for example you want that the items that were initially invalid (that is, where the scale is 0) are always editable, am I correct? I assume that "0 microns" is invalid for what should be editable, but if after the user replaces it with 100 microns then it is already valid and should not be editable. Am I right or not?

Comment: @abk Maybe you have an idea that you have not expressed correctly in your question and therefore I understand something else, I'm asking you for the third time to improve your question to be clear and concise avoiding confusion

Comment: Yes. that's the requirement.